# C2664 error with boost depth_first_search.hpp when compiling with /clr

Tags: .net, boost, c++-cli, interop, visual-studio-2015

A library I am using, uses the boost depth_first_search.hpp. When i try to compile i get a very long error message:

```
Error C2664 'boost::type_traits::no_type boost::detail::has_member_function_finish_edge_detail_hcmf<BOOST_TTI_DETAIL_TP_T>::chkt<has_member_function_finish_edge_detail_hcmf<BOOST_TTI_DETAIL_TP_T>::cl_type<BOOST_TTI_DETAIL_TP_T>::type>(...)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'nullptr' to '...'
```

The error message points to this line:

```
BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(finish_edge)
```

In depth_first_search.hpp. This resolves through several preprocessor macros to some very long function, apparently intended to check for the existence of a function called finish_edge.

I have tried a few different things to get it to work and to identify the problem. I have found the error only happens if I compile with the /CLR flag. I have set up an empty project where the only thing in main.cpp is `#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>` and an empty main. If i compile the project with /CLR thes issue is there, but if remove /CLR, it compiles fine.

The problem is that I need clr support as I am writing a set of wrappers for use with C#. I tried compiling depth_first_search.hpp as unmanaged as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302784/including-headers-from-an-unmanaged-c-code-inside-c-cli-code), but it didn't work.

Additionally i have found that I can comment out the function, and it seemingly works fine, but i would like to have work without doing a hack like that.

How do I get boost to play nice with C++CLI?

EDIT: I have created a SSCCE [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6399753/BoostErrorSSCCE.zip). The project properties should obviously be updated such that the additional include directories is points to boost.

Here's the main file:

```
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, C++/CLI is based on an older version of C++ and got little love since. So, things are bound to be difficult.

Comment: "I tried compiling ... as unmanaged ..., but it didn't work." vs. "How do I get boost to play nice with C++CLI?". It sounds to me you're barking up the wrong tree. Make a SSCCE I'll fix it (preferrably the unmanaged version)

Comment: @Deduplicator BGL is entirely c++03 proof though

Comment: @sehe: Well, that makes it unlikely it's a problem with compiling the boost library as C++/CLI then at least. Thanks for that info.

Comment: I am putting together a SSCCE and will put it up in a bit. @Deduplicator. Why remove the C++ tag. This is about interop between C++-cli and regular C++. Surely both tags apply.

Comment: You want to compile it as C++/CLI, so no. BTW: The [mcve] should be in the question itself.

Comment: I updated the question to include a SSCCE. I disagree about the tag, since I am clearly trying to use unmanaged code (i.e. regular C++) together with C++-cli. While this question might be very specific to boost, it is not unthinkable that this issue might apply to other native libraries and is thus relevant to the C++ tag.

Comment: Taus, I'm looking at it live: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/ (also, WTF a 35 (!!!) MiB download?!? SSCCE?)

Comment: Ok, here's the reduced sample: [gist](https://gist.github.com/sehe/9b279a147ab5a4691986) - that downloads 4.3KiB, a 500,000x reduction - I would need time and MSVC to actually test this. Not today.

Comment: Sorry about the size. I forgot that VS creates a few big files that are not actually needed to load the project and didn't think about it. I uploaded a smaller example to the question as well. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: @Manu the "obvious" solution is a  mixed mode assembly and separation of C++ only implementation that includes the boost headers, and a CLR-enabled translation unit that calls that implementation. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I did now find a workaround for it.

When commenting out the line BOOST_TTI_HAS_MEMBER_FUNCTION(finish_edge)
and replacing the line
do_call_finish_edge

it works for me...