# Convert VC++ Project into C#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have gone over this two Qs:

[Possible to call C++ code from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c)

[Wrapping unmanaged C++ with C++/CLI - a proper approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642702/wrapping-unmanaged-c-with-c-cli-a-proper-approach)

I also read few things about `C++/CLI` , but honestly I am pretty confused.

I have a `VC++` Project and I want to convert it into a `C#` Project.

My Qs are:

1. Do I need to use `C++/CLI` for this purpose and how?
2. Do I have to implement a wrapper class for each method of the original Project on my new Project and If not how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Yes you need C++/CLI

2) No you don't need to make a wrapper class for each method, you need to make just one wrapper class for each C++(native) class you have, its similar to declare an interface

[Wrapping unmanaged C++ with C++/CLI - a proper approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935664/possible-to-call-c-code-from-c)

is an exampe with just one method, but if yuor class written in C++ of type NativeType have another method, for example:

```
void Method2()
```

just had on the same class

```
   void ManagedMethod2()
      { NativePtr->Method2(); }
```

so the entire wrapper class will be:
    #include "NativeType.h"

```
public ref class ManagedType
{
     NativeType*   NativePtr; 

public:
     ManagedType() : NativePtr(new NativeType()) {}
     ~ManagedType() { delete NativePtr; }

     void ManagedMethod()
      { NativePtr->NativeMethod(); } 

     void ManagedMethod2()
      { NativePtr->Method2(); } 
};
```

always from the link above for call the method2 in C# you will do:

```
mt.ManagedMethod2();
```