# How to use a C++ class in C# windows application?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use c++ class method in my c# windows application

I use this

```
[DllImport("ZKNetLib.dll", EntryPoint = "ZK_NET_DEV_SetEventCallBack")]
public static extern int ZK_NET_DEV_SetEventCallBack(int u32Handle, ref OnEventCallBack u32Event, IntPtr pUserData);
```

to import the dll and their method

But, in dll method there are some other methods are also used, which i find very tough to find out what exactly is happening. Like, in above import there is "OnEventCallBack" method that dll is using. So, is there any way to use these c++ class and header files in my windows application.

I, heard of using c# application class in c++ by making the class object and using there namespace.

So, i was wondering there should be any way of using these header file and class into my c# application too?

Below is the edited question

ZK_NET_DEV_SetDataCallBack
This function is used for information data callback.
HI_S32  ZK_NET_DEV_SetDataCallBack (
HI_U32              u32Handle
HI_ON_DATA_CALLBACK cbDataCallBack,
HI_VOID*            pUserData
);

Parameters
    u32Handle
        [IN] Operation handle
    cbDataCallBack
        [IN] Information data callback function
    pUserData
        [IN] User data

Callback Function
typedef  HI_S32  (*HI_ON_DATA_CALLBACK)(
HI_U32      u32Handle,
HI_U32      u32DataType,
HI_U8*      pu8Buffer,
HI_U32      u32Length,
HI_VOID*    pUserData
);

Callback Function Parameters
    u32Handle
        Operation handle
    u32DataType
        Data type
Macro Definition    Value   Meaning
ZK_NET_DEV_MOTION_DETECTION 0   Motion detection alarm
ZK_NET_DEV_INPUT_ALARM  1   Input alarm
ZK_NET_DEV_KEEP_ALIVE   2   Heartbeat packet
    pu8Buffer
Data. If the value of u32DataType is ZK_NET_DEV_MOTION_DETECTION, pu8Buffer is stored as HI_S_ALARM_MD.
typedef struct 
{
    HI_U32      u32Area;            //Area
    HI_U32      u32X;           //x coordinate
    HI_U32      u32Y;           //y coordinate
    HI_U32      u32Width;       //Rectangular width
    HI_U32      u32Height;      //Rectangular height
} HI_S_ALARM_MD;
The maximum value of u32Area is 4. Related data is as follows:
Macro Definition    Value   Meaning
ZK_NET_DEV_MOTION_AREA_1    1   Area 1
ZK_NET_DEV_MOTION_AREA_2    2   Area 2
ZK_NET_DEV_MOTION_AREA_3    3   Area 3
ZK_NET_DEV_MOTION_AREA_4    4   Area 4
    u32Length
Data length. If the value of u32DataType is ZK_NET_DEV_MOTION_DETECTION and alarms are generated in two areas, the value of u32Length is:
u32Length = 2*sizeof(HI_S_ALARM_MD)
    u32DataType
        User data

Return Values
HI_SUCCESS is returned for a successful operation and HI_ FAILURE for a failed operation.

Comment: You mentioned "C++ class" but the code is referencing something that looks like a global function, `ZK_NET_DEV_SetEventCallBack`. There's no class here.

Comment: You might not read the question properly. ZK_NET_DEV_SetEventCallBack is a dll method. And, this dll method accessing another c++ class method like 'OnEventCallBack', that are declared and defined in c++ code. So, is there any way to directly use this class into my c# application.

Comment: Through COM you can access a C++ class and its methods,

Comment: I don't know how to access a C++ class and its methods using COM, Can you please guide me in doing so.

Comment: Please, post the relevant information from the C(++) header file of the DLL - that is, the method definition and the callback method definition. A simple method call like this definitely does not need a C++.NET intermediate :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642702/wrapping-unmanaged-c-with-c-cli-a-proper-approach

Comment: Below is full user manual to use these c++ dll.

Comment: This function is used for event data callback.
HI_S32  ZK_NET_DEV_SetEventCallBack(HI_U32 u32HandleHI_ON_EVENT_CALLBACK cbEventCallBack, HI_VOID* pUserData);
Parameters u32Handle [IN] Operation handle,cbEventCallBack [IN] Event data callback function,pUserData [IN] User data

Comment: Callback Function
 typedef  HI_S32  (*HI_ON_EVENT_CALLBACK) (
HI_U32   u32Handle,
HI_U32   u32Event,
HI_VOID*  pUserData
);

Callback Function Parameters
 u32Handle
  Operation handle
 u32Event
  Event
Macro Definition Value Meaning
ZK_NET_DEV_CONNECTING 0 Connecting
ZK_NET_DEV_CONNECTED 1 Connected
ZK_NET_DEV_CONNECT_FAILED 2 Connection failed
ZK_NET_DEV_ABORTIBE_DISCONNECTED 3 Disconnected
ZK_NET_DEV_NORMAL_DISCONNECTED 4 Disconnected
ZK_NET_DEV_RECONNECTING 5 Reconnecting
ZK_NET_DEV_RECORD_START 6 Recording started
ZK_NET_DEV_RECORD_STOP 7 Recording stopped
 pUserData
  User data

Comment: You should edit your question and add this information to the question itself..

Comment: It really depends on how your c++ dll and export and conventions are done. Do you have access to c++ code?

Comment: Yes, I do access to my c++ code. And, i want to create my application using its dll and method in c#.

Answer (score 1):

SWIG by far is the most reliable option you can use (recommended by Mono guys as it supports even Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android)

http://www.swig.org/

As it has been used in too many scenarios (Java, C# and so on).

There are of course other alternatives, such as cxxi from Mono and so on, but if SWIG works for you then  why use them?